# IronPython entity framwork 6 Could not find attribute where

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ironpython

I have successfully integrated entity framework into my project. I'm also able to read data from a table over my dbcontext. But when i try to use the linq `where` method, i get the following error message: **'DbSet[Workflow]' object has no attribute 'Where'**

This is my code:

```
import clr
import sys
from Framework.EF import MyDbContext, Workflow
from System import Console
from System.Linq import Enumerable, IQueryable
from System import Linq

context = MyDbContext()

Console.WriteLine(     context.Workflow.Where(lambda x: x.DisplayName == 'ABC123').ToList()[0].DisplayName          )
```

Maybe some one has experiances with linq and ironpython.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issues; I had to use import:

```
import clr
import System
clr.ImportExtensions(System.Linq)
```